# Create task for OpenApi Spring Boot 3 in gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, openapi, springdoc

I am trying to create a task for gradle which will download spec to build folder.
I am using
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0' and SpringBoot 3v

```
task generateOpenApiSpec(type: JavaExec) {
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
main = 'org.springdoc.api.OpenApiResource'

systemProperty 'springdoc.api-docs.path', '/v3/api1-docs'
systemProperty 'springdoc.swagger-ui.path', '/swagger-ui.html'
systemProperty 'springdoc.output-dir', 'build/generated-specs'

doFirst {
    file("$buildDir/generated-specs").mkdirs()
}

}
```

It's not work.
Also i am trying :

```
task downloadFile(type: Exec) {
dependsOn 'bootRun'
commandLine 'curl', '-o', 'build/generated-specs', 'http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs'
 }
```

I want the build to save the spec to the build folder.The first example should work, but with  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.0"
id("org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin") version "1.6.0", but i use springVersion=3.0.6

```
task startApplication {
dependsOn 'classes'

doLast {
    javaexec {
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        main = 'com.telekom.onecpq.bffcatalog.CatalogApplication' // Replace with the main class of your Spring application
    }
}
```

}

```
task downloadFile1 {
dependsOn startApplication
doFirst {
    // Wait for the application to start
    Thread.sleep(50)
    // Execute the downloadFile task
    def url = new URL('https://example.com/swagger-ui.html')
    def outputFile = file('build/generated-specs/swagger-ui.html')
    outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    outputFile.withWriter { writer ->
        url.openStream().withReader { reader ->
            writer << reader.text
        }
    }
}
```

}

Started TestApplication in 5.099 seconds (process running for 6.763)

Comment: It would probably be easier to assist you in case you told us which problem you encountered, rather than stating that it does not work. Have you tried running with --stacktrace or --info to get some informative description of the problem

Comment: Is there a way to start the application and download the file by url in gradle task. And is there another way to do this, because gradle plugin doesn't work with 3rd version of spring.

Comment: You keep saying it doesn't work, not what the problem is. Anyway, there is no easy way of executing a JavaExec task in background, but perhaps this one may help a bit: https://github.com/psxpaul/gradle-execfork-plugin

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [gradle plugin](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin) for that now

```
plugins {
      id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.7.0"
      id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.6.0"
}
openApi {
    apiDocsUrl.set("https://localhost:9000/api/docs")
    outputDir.set(file("$buildDir/docs"))
    outputFileName.set("swagger.json")
    waitTimeInSeconds.set(10)
    groupedApiMappings.set(["https://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/groupA" to "swagger-groupA.json",
                            "https://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/groupB" to "swagger-groupB.json"])
    customBootRun {
        args.set(["--spring.profiles.active=special"]) 
    }
}
```

This is the default shown configuration. I'm sure you can use that as a starting point to get your spec in the universal format